# Javascript - CreateStore - Passing multiple functions as only one parameter - Redux - React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to pass multiple enhancer functions to the createStore function of Redux.

This approach did **NOT** worked:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, [composeWithDevTools(), applyMiddleware()]); // !!!!! Remove composeWith Dev FOR RELEASE
```

this was worked when i only passed the DevTools enhancer:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

im working with React Native for information.
How can i pass multiple Enhancer to the CreateStore function?
Thank you for your help

## EDIT: - SOLVED

after some trying and getting some knowledge about composers (thanks to the tip from the answere) i found the right usage:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want the `compose` function from redux. Here's an example with many enhancers, which is also documented [in the Redux "Configuring Your Store" docs page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store).

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(loggerMiddleware, thunkMiddleware)

const composedEnhancers = compose(middlewareEnhancer, monitorReducersEnhancer)

const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers)
```

Comment: The bundling of arrays only to spread them again is needless, just pass the parameters in directly.

Comment: Thank your for your answere but it did not worked. after a bit of trying i found the solution since the function composeWithDevTools() is a composer and not an Enhancer.